# How to Mock RestTemplate by using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I've written Powermockito condition , but its not working. Can any one help me on it.

ResponseEntity response =  new RestTemplate().exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockPoint);

Answer (score 0):

Below Answer is correct..

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(EPartnerMicroServiceHelper.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class EPartnerMicroServiceHelperTest {

    private EPartnerMicroServiceHelper ePartnerMicroServiceHelper;

    @Mock
    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity;
    @Mock
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ePartnerMicroServiceHelper = new EPartnerMicroServiceHelper();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveAllUserDetails() throws Exception {
        String loggerId = "loggerId";

        MemberSearchCriteriaDTO memberSearchCriteriaDTO = new MemberSearchCriteriaDTO();
        memberSearchCriteriaDTO.setBrokerCode("brokerCode");

        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("some response body", HttpStatus.OK);

        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = mock(RequestEntity.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(RequestEntity.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(requestEntity);

        RestTemplate mockPoint = mock(RestTemplate.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockPoint);

        PowerMockito.when(mockPoint.exchange(requestEntity, String.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);  


        ePartnerMicroServiceHelper.retrieveAllUserDetails(loggerId, memberSearchCriteriaDTO);
    }
```